# Azure Function automatic retry on failure UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, promise, azure-functions, node-fetch, azure-durable-functions

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
let url = 'something.com';

module.exports = function(context) {
  let a = fetch(url)

  a.then(res => {
    if(res.status!=200) throw new Error(res.statusText)
    else{
      context.done(null, res.body);
    }
  });
  a.catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      throw new Error(err)
  });

};
```

I have a durable function that calls an activity function like above. I have set automatic retry on failure on this activity function. To retry the function needs to get an error.

So In get request I want to throw an error when i get response like 404 or something similar. But when i throw from catch block i get an error like below

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch().

function pauses there and stops execution.I have to manually stop and start the execution. How can i handle this so that the function retries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that with the use of `async/await` this problem goes away and the function re-try after exception is thrown.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
let url = 'something.com';

module.exports = async function(context) {

  let res = await fetch(url)

  if(res.status!=200) throw new Error(res.statusText);
  else return res.body;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code branches.

Ignoring the detail, what you have is :

```
let a = <Promise>; // root
a.then(...); // branch_1
a.catch(...); // branch_2
```

So whereas you catch errors arising in `a`, any error arising in branch 1 will be uncaught. Hence the warning

Compare that with :

```
let a = <Promise>; // root
a.then(...).catch(...); // branch
```

or

```
<Promise>.then(...).catch(...); // no assignment necessary
```

So, you might write :

```
module.exports = function(context) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.status!=200) {
            throw new Error(res.statusText);
        } else {
            context.done(null, res.body);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        throw new Error(err)
    });
};
```

Alternatively, depending on the required division of responsibilities between module and caller(s) ...

```
module.exports = function(context) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.status!=200) {
            throw new Error(res.statusText);
        } else {
            return res;
        }
    });
};
```

... and call `.context.done(null, res.body);` in a `.then()` callback in the caller.

In both cases, with `return` included, then the caller will need to catch errors otherwise you will again get an unhandled error warning.

Comment: I tried the non branching promise before. When the catch block throws the error i get `unhandled error warning`. With out throwing error my function will not re-start. Is there no way for the caller to throw error with out catching it? @Roamer-1888

Comment: If you don't return Promise from the fnction, then simply don't re-throw the error; it will be caught and stay caught. If you return Promise from the function then re-throw the error in the catch block, and heed my last paragraph.